# Mysql Insert value from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, cartesian-product

I have two tables : **table1(t1_id, t1_name)**,
**table2(t2_id, t1_id)**.

now if i try to insert value into table2 like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2(t2_id, t1_id) values(110202,(SELECT t1_id FROM table1));
```

This create an error : "subquery returns more than 1 row", which means it can insert only one row. **But i want to insert all cartesian product.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you are looking for this

```
INSERT INTO table2(t2_id, t1_id)

SELECT 110202,t1_id FROM table1
```